# Use a wild card to unset sessions with a prefix (php)?

Tags: php, session

I am using PHP to set session variables that all begin in cont_ so `$_SESSION['cont_`... now I cannot use `$_SESSION['cont']['subvariable'];` for a very server-related, specific reason. I tried doing `unset($_SESSION['cont_'*];` but that gives out errors.

What would the best way be to do this without having to set `$_SESSION['cont']['var'];`?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val){
    if(substr($key,0,5) === "cont_"){
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds. Hat's off.

Comment: this is what I am trying with your code: `<?php
 session_start();
 var_dump($_SESSION);
 
 
 echo "<hr><hr>";
 
 
 foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val){
    if(substr($key,0,4) === "cont_"){
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
 var_dump($_SESSION);` and when I var_dump it the second time, cont_* are all still there, anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you literally have an asterisk in your `session` key?

Comment: @wanovak no but I wanted to use one just like it is used in css, htaccess and stuff :) ps please check the edit I made to your answer, I think it has to be 5 as the end of substr instead of 4

Comment: I want to mark this as the answer but would like you to fix the error first :D

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to loop through the array, find the ones starting with `cont_` and unset those.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $val) {
    if (preg_match('/$cont_/', $key)) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```